# Can asymptotes be any straight line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was thinking if graphs can have  asymptotes as x=y or any other random line . I couldn't think of a function . please help

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you want tag [tag:graphing-functions] rather than tag [tag:graph-theory].  Consider $x^2-y^2=1$

Comment: Principally yes, any straight line can be an asymptote. But where is this question coming from?

Comment: [Have fun](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vmfhld28g2)! (Move the slider to change the value of $m$.)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC:  that should be an answer!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Done!

Answer (score 5):

The function $f(x)=ax+b$ obviously has asymptote $y=ax+b$. To make things not that trivial, you may add things that shrink to $0$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$.
For example, the function $$f(x)=ax+b+\frac{1}{x+1}$$ will also have $y=ax+b$ as asymptote. It is easy to see that you can find rational functions that have asymptote $y=ax+b$ using this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a graph with an asymptote that is any line. Check out this [Desmos figure](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oitv4ov4vu) and play around the sliders for the values of $t$, $a$, and $b$ to see. Have fun!

Though I should mention that that graph is almost never the graph of a function. If you specifically wanted to limit yourself to graphs of functions then @duraince's answer is better.

Comment: Nice De(s)mo(s); +$1$

Comment: Thanks. I was going to add the angle between the lines as yet another parameter, but ya gotta know when enough's enough, right?